# Get the mean from cells between 2 row numbers in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Sorry for the unclear title, I have difficulties describing the problem in a single sentence.

In two cells, I have 2 numbers. Those numbers correspond to rows in another sheet.

What I need is to obtain the mean value of all the cells in a fixed column, between those 2 rows.

It seems to kind of work when the data is on the same sheet, but fails otherwise.

If I have the row numbers in cells `B15` and `C15`, and the data is in column K, on the same sheet, the following code works :

```
=MEAN(INDEX(K:K;B15):INDEX(K:K;C15))
```

But, if the data is in another sheet, the following code does not work (invalid syntax) :

```
=MEAN(Sheet2!INDEX(K:K;B15):INDEX(K:K;C15))
```

I understand that after referencing another sheet, you cannot call a function immediately, but must put a cell coordinate. So, that is a first problem, since the coordinate of the first cell I want can vary. But, what I find strange, is that if I put a fixed first cell, the syntax is good, but i get a #VALUE! error :

```
=MEAN(Sheet2!K1:INDEX(K:K;C15))
```

Does INDEX() not work across sheets?

Comment: it does but you need to also include the sheet name in the INDEX: `=MEAN(Sheet2!K1:INDEX(Sheet2!K:K;C15))`

Comment: @ScottCraner ah yes, thank you, you already solved half of my problem :)

Comment: And I found, with the help of your comment, how to solve my last problem ! Many thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help from @ScottCraner, I finally found what my formula should be :

`=MOYENNE(INDEX(Feuil2!K:K;B15):INDEX(Feuil2!K:K;C15))`